# How to convert from 1D array to 2D array using malloc

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I'm trying to convert the a 1D array to a 2D array

Answer (score 3):

If you want to allocate an actual 2D array, not an array of pointers, the syntax gets a little tricky:

```
int X = 16, Y = 8;
char (*pt)[X][Y] = malloc(X*Y);
```

Above, `pt` is a pointer to an `X` by `Y` array of `char`s. Because it's a pointer, accessing its elements requires an asterisk and parentheses, too:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != X ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j != Y ; j++) {
        (*pt)[i][j] = (char)(i*X+j);
    }
}
```

Of course you need to free the pointer once you are done using the array:

```
free(pt);
```

Comment: wow.. i don't know this... I wonder what would be the syntax to pass this array as an argument.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate each row of the matrix separately:

```
unsigned char** index;

index = malloc(X * sizeof(unsigned char*)); // Allocate an array of pointers

for(int i = 0; i < X; i++)
    index[i] = malloc(Y * sizeof(unsigned char)) // Allocate each row
```

Refer also to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) on malloc pointer casting.

Answer (score 1):

After your edit, it appears you are using C++.

In C++, you should **prefer** `std::vector< std::vector< unsigned char > >` for dynamic 2d array.

```
std::vector< std::vector< unsigned char > > index(X, std::vector<unsigned char>(Y));
```

Now you can use it as `index[i][j]` and it will be automatically cleaned, so need to free/delete explicitly.

[Live demo here](http://ideone.com/dVH6oX)

Still if you want to allocate c-compliant arrays in conventional way, use

```
unsigned char** index;

try {
  index = new int*[X];
  for(int i = 0; i < X; ++i)
    index[i] = new int[Y];
} catch(...) {...}
```

For delete also you need to delete each element individually.

---

**Old answer**

```
unsigned char        **index;
index = malloc(X * sizeof *index);
if(!index) fail();
for(xi = 0; xi < X; ++xi) {
  index[xi] = malloc(Y * sizeof **index);
  if(!index[xi]) free_and_fail();
}
```

You first allocate space for X pointers and then in all X pointers you allocate one array.

While freeing the memory, you need to free each row individually:

```
if(index) for(xi = Y-1; xi >= 0; --xi) { /* xi is signed */
  free(index[xi];
}
free(index);
index = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char **index;
index = (unsigned char**)malloc( X*Y );
```

is wrong. `index` is an `unsigned char**`. You need to `malloc` two times to get a 2D array. If you want to allocate `X` rows, each with `Y` columns, use

```
unsigned char **index;
index = (unsigned char**)malloc( X * sizeof(unsigned char*) ); //Allocating number of rows
for(int i=0 ; i<X ; i++ ) 
{
    index[i] = (unsigned char*)malloc( Y * sizeof(unsigned char)); // Allocate each column
}
```

You should check if `malloc` does not fail. You should also `free` everything after its use to avoid a *memory leak*.

Comment: I'm getting this error : a vlue of type "void*" cannot be assigned to a value of type "unsigned char*"

Comment: The title of this question says that you compile in C. But, that error message can only come when you are compiling in C++.